# How to make a jquery take new value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function where the default value is `1`, but when a specific radio button is checked, I want that value to become `5`. In console it shows the correct value, but on the website it doesn't.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  value = 1;
  $('#radio').click(function() {
   if($('#radio2').is(':checked')) {
     value = 5;
   } else {
     value = 1;
   };
  });

valuePicker("#valuePicker", value);    
});
```

I need somehow to reload this `valuePicker` function when radio button is selected, otherwise it will always take the default option.

Comment: Can't you just put the `valuePicker()` call *inside* the `click` handler?

Answer (score 0):

> I need somehow to reload this valuePicker function when radio button
>   is selected, otherwise it will always take the default option.

You need to *reload* the `valuePicker` at the `click` event of the *radio button*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     value = 1;
     $('#radio').click(function() {
         if($('#radio2').is(':checked'))  
         {
             valuePicker("#valuePicker", 5);    //this line is added
         } 
         else 
         {
             valuePicker("#valuePicker", 1);    //this line is added
         };
     });
     valuePicker("#valuePicker", value);    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only updating valuePicker when the page loads, you need to call it inside the radio update function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  value = 1;
  $('#radio').click(function() {
   if($('#radio2').is(':checked')) {
     value = 5;
   } else {
     value = 1;
   };
   valuePicker("#valuePicker", value);    
  });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 value = 1;
 $('#radio').click(function() {
     valuePicker("#valuePicker", $('#radio2').is(':checked') ? 5 : 1);
 });
 valuePicker("#valuePicker", value);    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When radio2 is not selected and you try to select first radio button then it will print '1' and after selecting second radio just click on the first radio button it will print '5' in the textbox

for now, i have used checkbox so you can check by checked and unchecked both

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  value = 1;
  $('#radio').click(function() {
   if($('#radio2').is(':checked')) {
     value = 5;
   } else {
     value = 1;
   };
   valuePicker("#valuePicker", value);    
  });    
});

function valuePicker(id, value){
  $(id).val(value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Radio1 <input type='radio' id='radio' name='radio'>
Radio2 <input type='checkbox' id='radio2' name='radio2'>

<input type='text' id='valuePicker'>
```